# Php file outputting javascript for include as a JS file - need to restrict so its not opened in a browser window

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

I'm storing configuration details in a database which I need to use in javascript. I'm accessing all this using php and instead of outputting all the details into inline javascript code on the main page I've instead created a php file that outputs content type javascript and refernce it in my main page as an external javascript file.

I want to set it up so that it can't be viewed in a browser window i.e :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phpFileThatDoesJS.php" ></script>
```

should work but typing `www.mysite.com/phpFileThatDoesJS.php` in the browser shouldn't

EDIT ==========

The thing is that I have to edit a script that for some oddball reason stores the username and password of a user in a javascript Object and outputs it within script tags. I have to set it up so that this is not viewable by a simple view source action. Thats why I thought of referencing it as an external javascript.

Isnt there any htaccess tricks that I could use?

Comment: Sounds impossible/impractical to try to hide a JS file like that. I'd be questioning you as to what kind of configuration details you'd need to store and access via JS that can't be done in the PHP being called by said javascript.

Comment: forget about hiding to the user something you push to the user :-)

Comment: Ali - The problem is not the user viewing javascript. You can in theory have a web browser that simply hides javascript permanently, but this does not restrict users from trying other tools, such as sniffing network. When it comes to security, there's one major policy everyone agrees on: **never trust the user**.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of, and it isn't reliable, is to check the [HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) header. Other than that, there isn't a difference between a browser requesting the resource through a `<script>` tag and a user browsing to it directly.

Additionally, you do realize that the user will still be able to see/access the source code.

-- Answer to your updated question ------

Nope. If you send it to the browser, the end user can access it.

-- Further answering your updated question -----

Really I must wonder why you are wanting to store the username/password of a user in Javascript. Is this something you plan on actually using with Javascript as in sending it to a remote site? Or is it something you plan on sending back to the server through a form or an Ajax style of request?

If you plan on sending it back to the server, why not use Session variables?

Comment: Hmmm whats the catch in using the HTTP Referer header?

Comment: They are not always sent. I know for a fact that versions of Norton Internet Security suite disables sending the HTTP referrer as a "security precaution". Additionally, they are super easy to fake.

Comment: Blocking access if the referer header is not sent will cause the script to be blocked for some users **all** the time (including when loading it as part of the page). It won't stop people loading the page, then looking at the script in Firebug, or grabbing a copy with Charles Proxy, or half a dozen other methods.

Comment: Dang, isn't there anyway to restrict displaying of javascript code

Comment: Actually it isn't even my code, I have to edit it for a client who bought this application off the web. Whenever he logs in - the page for some reason stores his login details on the page itself.

Comment: @Ali - The best recommendation then, is to go through the code and determine why it's there, if it is needed, and update accordingly. I'm sorry, but this sounds like a poorly designed application :(

Answer (score 1):

did you gave the content type as `application/javascript` in the php file before the output starts
like

```
header ("Content-type: application/javascript");
```

-- update
If you are using the js then it is visible to the user. you cannot hide what is in the js script.

and about htaccess you can change the .php to .js using .htaccess

try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /
RewriteRule externaljs.js$ externaljs.php$1 [L]
```

then u can call the same file like

```
http://yoursite.com/externaljs.js and the externaljs.php will be executed
```

Comment: To add to Anush's answer: also use      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="something.js"');

Comment: @CaroeBictumDC actually content-disposition is not nessary, it only make sure that if u gave the link directly it will be asked to be saved rather than opening as a js file.

Comment: Actually this is great but I want to be able to restrict the user from viewing the javascript code...